# Store path of file in a variable JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to store the this file and it's path in a variable somehow like so:

```
var interaction ="css/interaction1/styles.css";
```

As later on I need to wait until this file loads before performing an action, ie wait until dynamically loaded CSS file loads before loading the content.

```
$(interaction).load(function(){
            loadContent();
});
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: css/interaction1/styles.css
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are trying to perform a load method of a string. That is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can't do it like that. You can do this instead:

```
$('<link />', {
    href: interaction,
    type: "stylesheet"
}).appendTo('head');
```

The above is how you load css dynamically. The `interaction` is not a valid selector that jQuery knows and hence the error.

Comment: hi yes I already do this, bit that's not the problem, I already append the CSS to the head but then I need to wait until it loads before loading the content

Comment: @user, you can't reliably do that cross-browser. Some of the answers in the duplicate mention this.